# How to use `USE INDEX` with rank window in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I've created a custom index that drastically speeds up a large query I have. MySQL only uses this index if I add `USE INDEX (index_name)` after the `FROM table` clause.

I want to run the same query with an extra field, calculated as `PERCENT_RANK()` over the same `ORDER BY` as my usual query.

But when I do this, the query runs 50x slower:

```
SELECT s.ranking FROM (
  SELECT PERCENT_RANK() OVER (
    ORDER BY foo DESC, bar ASC  -- same ordering as my normal query
  ) AS ranking
  FROM my_table
  USE INDEX (my_index)
  WHERE id = 1234
) s
```

`explain format=json` shows that the windowing function is examining every single row in my table. Is there some syntax that ensures the windowing function's `ORDER BY` uses the same index?

Comment: The Primary Key being an Integer isn't the most efficient indexing method?  Or in other words .. why not use an Auto Incrementing Primary Key in Integer format?  If you already have a primary key but aren't using it .. why?  And if you don't have one .. here make one like this:
alter table `table_name` add primary key(`column_name`);

Comment: I'm trying to order by non-primary columns in the window function. Selecting the row from the ranked window is easy with the primary integer key `id`, but the actual ranking seems to be what's taking so much time. That's why I'm trying to use the index I already have over `foo DESC, bar ASC`.

The data is updated very frequently so I can't simply add another column with the current rank.

Comment: Provide complete `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;` output. Optimal index for shown query seems to be `(id, foo DESC, bar)`. And outer query is obviously excess in it, use your subquery as final query.

Comment: @Akina don't I need the outer query for the WHERE clause? If the WHERE is inside the window function, the rank will always be 1 for that one row.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  Meanwhile, we can only guess at what is in `my_index`!